# C#: Get value of dynamic column names using LINQ to Datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable which has multiple columns & Rows but few column names are dynamic there. **see screen shot of my data table.**

[image]

**2010 FY 2011 FY** these column names are dynamic. now i have to fetch data from above **datatable by LINQ**. i use these condition to get data for 2010 FY.

here is my LINQ query but i do not know how to mention dynamic column name like 2010 FY.

```
    var data = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Section") == "Consensus Model"
        && x.Field<string>("Line Item") == "Net Sales" && x.Table.Columns["2010 FY"]).ToList();
```

i need to fetch data for 2010 FY along with other condition like when **Section is Consensus Model and Line Item is Net Sales**

so please guide me how to compose LINQ query which fetch **2010 FY's** Data which is **65225** with mentioning **Section & Line Item.**

thanks

Comment: Is this data from something like an Excel pivot table? It strikes me that your columns that have the dynamic titles are in fact rows of data in another table where the dynamic title is a field of text

Comment: yes data is coming from excel file which i load into datatable.

Comment: You need a Where() and a Select() : var data = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x => (x.Field<string>("Section") == "Consensus Model")) && (x.Field<string>("Line Item") == "Net Sales"))
        .Select(x => new { section = x.Field<string>("Section"), item = x.Field<string>("Line Item"), sales = x.Table.Columns["2010 FY"]})
        .ToList();

Comment: can't i use column name in where along with section & line item  ?

Comment: @jdweng sorry i test your code it did not work.

Comment: It should work.  I just had an extra parenthesis. I also changed the sales values to decimal.   What didn't work? :             var data = dt.AsEnumerable() .Where(x => (x.Field<string>("Section") == "Consensus Model") && (x.Field<string>("Line Item") == "Net Sales")) .Select(x => new { section = x.Field<string>("Section"), item = x.Field<string>("Line Item"), sales = x.Field<decimal>("2010 FY")}) .ToList();

Comment: Is the position of *dynamic* Column that is part of the query always the same? In this case, if you don't know in advance the Column's name, you can use its position (its index) instead.

Comment: @jdweng in where clause column name not mention

Comment: here you hard code sales name which will be dynamic column name. how to do it?

Comment: @jdweng yes your code worked but sales field name should be dynamic like column name....is it possible ?

Comment: It is a string.  So make it a variable. string year = "2010 FY";  sales = x.Field<decimal>(year)})

Comment: i am talking about column name sales which would dynamic name like column name.

Comment: Anything in double quotes are strings that can be replaced with a variable declared as a string.

Comment: i am talking about `sales = x.Field<decimal>(year)` here field name `sales ` is hard coded. how to make it dynamic?

Comment: How do you / expect your program to know which columns belong as the "dynamic" column names and which are not? How would it know to not include `Section` or `Line Item`?